# Активная вкладка меню на js

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который вроде как должен присваивать `class='active'` элементу `li` с `class='leftlinks'` при щелчке по нему, а с остальных элементов с `class='leftlinks'` убирать `class='active'`, но не присваивает. Где косяк?

```js
var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('leftlinks');
var onClick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    menuItems[i].classList.remove('active');
  }

  event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
};

for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="leftlinks">
    <div><img src="/img/1.png" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
    <a class="historyAPI" href="#">вкладка 1/a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="leftlinks">
                <div><img src="/img/2.png" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
                <a class="historyAPI" href="#">вкладка 2</a>
  </li>

  <li class="leftlinks">
    <div><img src="/img/3.png" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
    <a class="historyAPI" href="#">вкладка 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего ошибка была что вы тег `a` не закрыли

```js
var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName('leftlinks');
var onClick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    menuItems[i].classList.remove('active');
  }

  event.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
};

for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
  menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
}
```

```css
body {
font-family:sans-serif;
}
.leftlinks a{
color:#777;
}

.active a {
color:#000;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="leftlinks">
    <div><img src="/img/1.png" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
    <a class="historyAPI" href="#">вкладка 1</a>
            </li>

            <li class="leftlinks">
                <div><img src="/img/2.png" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
                <a class="historyAPI" href="#">вкладка 2</a>
  </li>

  <li class="leftlinks">
    <div><img src="/img/3.png" alt="" width="28" height="28"></div>
    <a class="historyAPI" href="#">вкладка 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```